# LINQ query with multiple aggregates

Tags: linq, .net-3.5, linq-to-objects

How would I create the equivalent Linq To Objects query?

```
SELECT MIN(CASE WHEN p.type = "In" THEN p.PunchTime ELSE NULL END ) AS EarliestIn,
       MAX(CASE WHEN p.type = "Out" THEN p.PunchTime ELSE NULL END ) AS LatestOUt
FROM Punches p
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't efficiently select multiple aggregates in vanilla LINQ to Objects. You can perform multiple queries, of course, but that may well be inefficient depending on your data source.

I have a framework which copes with this which I call "Push LINQ" - it's only a hobby (for me and Marc Gravell) but we believe it works pretty well. It's available as part of [MiscUtil](http://pobox.com/~skeet/csharp/miscutil), and you can read about it in [my blog post on it](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2008/01/04/quot-push-quot-linq-revisited-next-attempt-at-an-explanation.aspx).

It looks slightly odd - because you define where you want the results to go as "futures", then push the data through the query, then retrieve the results - but once you get your head round it, it's fine. I'd be interested to hear how you get on with it - if you use it, please mail me at skeet@pobox.com.

Comment: Thanks Jon.  One of the hardest parts about Linq so far is figuring out what you can and can't do.  I'll definitely take a look at your Push technique once I get a bit more comfortable with the standard methodology.

Answer (score 4):

Single enumeration yielding both min and max (and any other aggregate you want to throw in there).  This is much easier in vb.net.

I know this doesn't handle the empty case.  That's pretty easy to add.

```
    List<int> myInts = new List<int>() { 1, 4, 2, 0, 3 };
    var y = myInts.Aggregate(
        new { Min = int.MaxValue, Max = int.MinValue },
        (a, i) =>
        new
        {
           Min = (i < a.Min) ? i : a.Min,
           Max = (a.Max < i) ? i : a.Max
        });
    Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", y.Min, y.Max);
```

Comment: It is a bit manual but it is good enough for me.  It is funny how when you break linq down you quickly return to just syntactic shortcuts for  a foreach look.

Comment: Ironic then, isn't it?  foreach is just a syntactic shortcut.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to do multiple aggregates with LINQ-to-Objects, but it is a little ugly.

```
var times = punches.Aggregate(
    new { EarliestIn = default(DateTime?), LatestOut = default(DateTime?) },
    (agg, p) => new {
        EarliestIn = Min(
            agg.EarliestIn,
            p.type == "In" ? (DateTime?)p.PunchTime : default(DateTime?)),
        LatestOut = Max(
            agg.LatestOut,
            p.type == "Out" ? (DateTime?)p.PunchTime : default(DateTime?)) 
    }
);
```

You would also need Min and Max functions for DateTime since these are not available standard.

```
public static DateTime? Max(DateTime? d1, DateTime? d2)
{
    if (!d1.HasValue)
        return d2;
    if (!d2.HasValue)
        return d1;
    return d1.Value > d2.Value ? d1 : d2;
}
public static DateTime? Min(DateTime? d1, DateTime? d2)
{
    if (!d1.HasValue)
        return d2;
    if (!d2.HasValue)
        return d1;
    return d1.Value < d2.Value ? d1 : d2;
}
```