# Linq to NHibernate: Select multiple sums at once

Tags: sql, nhibernate, linq-to-nhibernate

Is there a way to select multiple sums at once using Linq to NHibernate?

Now I have

```
int? wordCount = (from translation in session.Query<TmTranslation>()
                  where translation.SatisfiesCondition
                  select translation.TranslationUnit)
                 .Sum(x => (int?)(x.WordCount + x.NumberCount)) ?? 0;

int? tagCount = (from translation in session.Query<TmTranslation>()
                 where translation.SatisfiesCondition
                 select translation.TranslationUnit)
                .Sum(x => (int?)(x.TagCount)) ?? 0;

int? characterCount = (from translation in session.Query<TmTranslation>()
                       where translation.SatisfiesCondition
                       select translation.TranslationUnit)
                      .Sum(x => (int?)(x.CharacterCount)) ?? 0;
```

which generates three different SQL queries. In SQL I can grab them all three at once, but is there a way to do this in Linq to NHibernate?

Thank you.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/154680/linq-query-with-multiple-aggregates

Comment: Did you want 3 sums in one query or all 3 queries sent to server in one trip? Either way both are definitely possible with QueryOver.

Comment: @dotjoe That would be great, do you have some example how to do that please? I wrote some queries using QueryOver, but when I needed something more complex, I usually found it very complicated and the official documentation does not help much, either.

Comment: @dotjoe And to answer your question, I intend to get all 3 sums in one query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having multiple aggregate functions within a `Select()` call works and results in a single SQL command sent to the database. For example:

```
var result = session.Query<TmAssignment>()
                    .Select(a => new
                    {
                       Words = session.Query<TmTranslation>().Where(s => s.Assignment == a).Sum(u => (int?) u.WordCount) ?? 0,
                       Others = session.Query<TmTranslation>().Where(s => s.Assignment == a).Sum(u => (int?)(u.TagCount + u.NumberCount)) ?? 0,
                    }).ToList();
```

Comment: Would be nice to see your solution

Comment: Soooo... What was your answer? I've never downvoted before, but this is not a useful answer.

Comment: @twoflower, Thank you for your update. You've given me something to consider for a query that I'm working on. Have you had any luck with grouping?

Comment: @mcfea Grouping seems to work fine in the NHibernate's LINQ provider. Do you have any particular issues?

Comment: @twoflower, indeed grouping compiles fine in NHibernate's LINQ provider, however, conditional selects do not. It essentially only returns a row count, I've since fallen back to QueryOver syntax for aggregations. I'm hopeful for the latest version of Nhibernate, but it doesn't look like they've addressed related tickets. If you can solve this persons question, you'll also solve mine: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15015662/expression-type-nhsumexpression-is-not-supported-by-this-selectclausevisitor

Answer (score 1):

this should help get you started with QueryOver way...

```
ResultDTO dtoAlias = null; //placeholder alias variable

var dto = session.OueryOver<TmTranslation>()
    .Where(x => x.SatisfiesCondition)
    //Change this to the actual type of Translation property
    .JoinQueryOver<Translation>(x => x.Translation)
    .SelectList(list => list
        //we can sum these columns individually to keep query simple,...add them together later
        .SelectSum(x => x.WordCount).WithAlias(() => dtoAlias.WordCountTotal)
        .SelectSum(x => x.NumberCount).WithAlias(() => dtoAlias.NumberCountTotal)
        //add more select sums to the select list
        )
    .TransformUsing(Transformers.AliasToBean<ResultDTO>())
    .SingleOrDefault<ResultDTO>();
```

Answer (score 0):

A potentially simpler solution I use is to do an artificial GroupBy then project to an anonymous object:

eg.

```
session.Query<TmTranslation>()
  .Where(o => o.SatisfiesCondition)
  .Select(o => o.TranslationUnit)
  .GroupBy(o => 1)
  .Select(o => new 
   {
     WordCount = o.Sum(x => (int?)(x.WordCount + x.NumberCount)) ?? 0,
     TagCount = o.Sum(x => (int?)(x.TagCount)) ?? 0,
     CharacterCount = o.Sum(x => (int?)(x.CharacterCount)) ?? 0
   })
  .Single();
```

This also produces just a single SQL statement and reduces the duplication nicely.