# Expression type 'NhSumExpression' is not supported by this SelectClauseVisitor

Tags: nhibernate, linq-to-nhibernate

I have a query that I can run in LinqPad, but not in NHibernate LINQ.  I found a similar bug on NHibernate Jira [NHibernate NH-2865](https://nhibernate.jira.com/browse/NH-2865), but I think this perhaps a different bug and I'm looking for possible alternatives.

The query that works in LinqPad using default LINQ to SQL is like this:

```
from ticket in LotteryTickets
  group tiket by ticket.ticketType into g

 select new
 {
     TicketType = g.Key,
     TotalWinningTickets = g.Count(b => b.WinAmount != 0),
     TotalWon = g.Sum(b => b.WinAmount * b.ticketWeight),
     TotalTickets = g.Count(),
 }
```

There are various other ways to count the TotalWinningTickets such as `TotalWinningTickets = g.Sum(t => t.WinAmount > 0 ? 1 : 0)` or `g.Sum(t => t.WinAmount == 0 ? 0 : 1)`

Now, with NHibernate LINQ I have been unable to get this working without changing my underlying db table.  My alternative was to add a table column called HasWon and I set it to 0 for false and 1 for true.  This does work, but I'm left feeling there is a better way other than modifying the db table.  Perhaps a subselect using a calculated field.  My NHibernate LINQ ended up looking like this:

```
from ticket in session.Query<Ticket>()
group ticket by ticket.TicketType into g
select new ReportRow
{
    TicketType = g.Key,
    TotalWinningBets = g.Sum(t => t.HasWon),
    TotalTickets = g.Count(),
    TotalWon = g.Sum(t => t.WinAmount * t.WagerWeight)
};
```

What I'm effectively trying to do is multiple Select COUNT in my NHibernate query, but based on different criteria.  The strangest this is that NHibernate converts all my `Count(t => t.???)` incorrectly into `COUNT(*)` in the generated SQL.

LinqPad generates SQL that works this way:
    SELECT SUM(
            (CASE 
                WHEN [t1].[WinAmount] > @p3 THEN @p4
                ELSE @p5
             END)) AS [value]

Hoping there is a better way.

Comment: I've looked around quite a bit and also not found a solution for this as yet. Any news on your front?